# Applying numpy functions to pandas.Series objects that operate on the entire values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to use the [`numpy.unwrap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html) function on a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object, but can't seem to figure out how to apply it:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> t = np.arange(0,1,0.05)
>>> ang = pd.Series((15*t)%(2*np.pi), t)
>>> np.unwrap(ang)
array([  0.  ,   0.75,   1.5 ,   2.25,   3.  ,   3.75,   4.5 ,   5.25,
         6.  ,   6.75,   7.5 ,   8.25,   9.  ,   9.75,  10.5 ,  11.25,
        12.  ,  12.75,  13.5 ,  14.25])
# this produces an np.array with the correct result, but not a Series
>>> ang.apply(np.unwrap)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3192, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1795, in unwrap
    dd = diff(p, axis=axis)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1571, in diff
    slice1[axis] = slice(1, None)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
>>> ang.map(np.unwrap)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2996, in map
    arg, na_action=na_action)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 1004, in _map_values
    new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1795, in unwrap
    dd = diff(p, axis=axis)
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1571, in diff
    slice1[axis] = slice(1, None)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I can use explicit construction of a new Series:

```
pd.Series(np.unwrap(ang), ang.index)
```

but this seems un-numpy-ish. Is there a better way? I suppose I could always create one, but that seems unsatisfying also:

```
def map_values(series, func):
    return pd.Series(func(series.values), series.index)
map_values(ang, np.unwrap)
```

Comment: Just curious, have you tried `ang[:] = np.unwrap(ang)`? It updates `ang` in-place.

Comment: interesting... in my case I would need to copy the array first, which is nicer than what I have in `map_values` in some ways, worse in others.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html#pandas-series-transform) but, surprisingly, it does not work right out the box. I got it to return a Series like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

t = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
ang = pd.Series((15 * t) % (2 * np.pi), t)

result = ang.to_frame().transform(np.unwrap).squeeze()
```

Doing `result = ang.transform(np.unwrap)` directly returns a numpy array, that is not what you want.

Comment: does this mean `transform` has a bug? (or `unwrap`?)

Comment: I cannot tell for sure, but it seems that transform does have a bug.